# The type 'System.IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I created a Windows Form application in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8, and the target .NET framework is 4.5, and I want to use the Datagramsocket library of Windows SDK, so I changed the target OS version to 8, when I compile.

I am getting the following error:

> "Error 1   The type 'System.IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'."

Comment: Wince. If I were you I'd consider having a dll to wrap 4.0 components up and using that from your 4.5 code just to keep which System is which all neat and tidy.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson 4.5 is an in-place upgrade, so you're always going to be using the 4.5 `System`.

Comment: @David, This datagram thingy doesn't agree with you, I'm happy to though. :)

Answer (score 32):

If you are targeting Windows 8, the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856306.aspx) has the following instructions:

> That said, your desktop app can’t consume much of anything from the
>   Windows Runtime until you prepare your project with one essential
>   reference. The Windows Runtime defines some standard classes and
>   interfaces in `System.Runtime`, such as `IEnumerable`, that are used
>   throughout the Windows Runtime libraries. By default, your managed
>   desktop app won’t be able to find these types, and so you must
>   manually reference System.Runtime before you can do anything
>   meaningful with Windows Runtime classes. To create this manual
>   reference:
>
> 1. Navigate to your managed desktop app project in the Solution Explorer.
> 2. Right-click the References node and click Add Reference.
> 3. Click the Browse tab.
> 4. Click Browse….
> 5. Navigate to the System.Runtime.dll façade. You can generally find this in a path similar to: `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll`

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is great analysis. For link to download the missing dll files, check out the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14517992/3918598

Comment: Thanks Nathan.  I copied the file over to my web project bin folder so that it could be packaged up with solution.  Add Reference > Solution > Project's Bin folder.

Answer (score 19):

If you run into this problem with 4.5.2 and Unity, Microsoft has issued a fix, KB article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2971005

Comment: This worked. Under Windows 10 I had to install the updated .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack.

Comment: Thanks Josh, however I am running VS2015 Enterprise Update 2 and I am still getting this issue.  Project is targeting 4.5.2.  If I manually add the reference in the web.config it works.  Since I am working on a group project and others are not hitting this issue I ideally don't want to add this as a fix.  Has anybody else found a fix or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Same on our build machine with Windows Server 2012, installing .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack hash fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue with Windows 10, TeamCity and VS2015:

**Symptoms:**

Visual studio builds the project fine, but TeamCity struggles with compile issues.

**Reason:**

Added a new project to existing solution - Forgot to change the TargetRuntimeVersion.

**Solution:**

Unload project

Edit .csproj file for that project

Change:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

To whatever you other projects are, or whatever is installed on the server.

For me it was:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Hope this helps anyone else experiencing this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your app is trying to load `System.Runtime` version 4.0, but that you don't have that version installed. You say you have .NET 4.5 installed, so you can provide some configuration to [redirect assembly bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) at runtime.

Try adding this to your `App.config` or `Web.config` file:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I haven't tested this exact scenario, but this configuration has helped me in similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

While working with a TFS build Agent I kept seeing this error below but only on a Windows 2012 R2 server with 4.5.2 installed. None of our Visual Studio machine ever had the compile error.

> "Error 1 The type 'System.IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'."

The cause as others have pointed out has to do with Portable Class Libraries and  as others have pointed out. but as for a solution some recommend a reference to the `System.Runtime.dll` facade in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll` I disagree as the path and version may be different on other machines.

Instead the best solution I've found was to install the [Windows SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx) on the build machine.

I found this solution from a post here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517873/what-install-files-in-location-program-files-x86-reference-assemblies-micros/14517992#14517992) and a really clear description as to why this problem occurs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675171/what-does-the-web-config-compilation-assemblies-element-do/19942274)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message in TeamCity after I added Unity 4.0.1 to the project that is targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1. I ended up copying missing folders in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework from my development machine to the build server. Both are running Windows 7. After that build succeeded.

[image]

Comment: That's probably not the best workaround.. (copying files)

Answer (score 1):

**Based on TFS 2015 Build Server**

I do not know if this error message is generic and the answers/solution may be unique for each unique error. But I had similar error `the type 'System.IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`

I realised that the project was using `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` and had interface `IUnityContainer` which implements `IDisposable`. It turned out that the TFS Build Definition NuGet Installer Build Step was not configured, which is responsible for restoring `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` NuGet package on the TFS Build Server. If you come across this error, please check your TFS Build Definition and point the NuGet Installer Build Step Path to your solution full path, including the .`sln` extension

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Josh mentions, I had this problem in a solution with a Web API project and several library projects, where one of the library projects was borking on build, with errors that said the Unity attributes weren't "valid" attributes, and then one of the errors said `The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly System.Runtime.`

The suggested "updated" 4.5.2 Developer Pack is what I already had installed, so that didn't help me. On a hunch I thought maybe it was just a version mismatch. So I looked at the properties of every project, and one of the very base libraries was targeting 4.5 while every other one was targeting 4.5.2. I changed that one to also target 4.5.2 and the errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in some solutions on VS 2015, and even in the same solution on one workstation but not on another. The errors started appeared after changing .NET version to 4.6.

The solution is simple: **Close the solution and delete the hidden .vs folder** in the same folder as the solution.

Adding the missing references as suggested in other answers also solves the problem, but the error remains solved even after you remove the references again.