# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' in deployed WPF ClickOnce App referencing MvvmLight from .Net Standard Library

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce, mvvm-light, .net-standard

I have a WPF App which references a .NET Standard 2.0 library which contains ViewModels and uses MvvmLight. I've created an error handler which listens for messages from the ViewModels using `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger`.

In visual studio, the app runs fine, but when I publish the app using ClickOnce then attempt to install and run it, the following exception occurs:

[image: FileNotFoundException]

The exception is thrown from the following line:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<Error>(this, ErrorHandler.DisplayError);
```

I was able to recreate the failure in a mostly empty project. The following is a link to a github repo with the project, if you'd like to see for yourself:
[SystemRuntimeFail Demo](https://github.com/kaitlynbrown/SystemRuntimeFail)

After 3 days searching through stackoverflow posts for information on how to fix this and trying just about everything, I'm very nearly at my wit's end. Please help!

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755274/visual-studio-2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4

Comment: Yes I did, and unfortunately it wasn't helpful. I had already had a reference to NetStandard.Library in my main project (I've added it to the SystemRuntimeFail demo now as well). I also tried adding a binding redirect, but unfortunately I don't know what version I'm supposed to be redirecting to, and I'm not really sure how to figure that out either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by adding binding redirects to app.config for each assembly that this happened with.

I was tripped up by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44590218/8610083) which included a `<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">` tag enclosing all of the `<dependentAssembly>`s. When I tried this, it didn't work. It wasn't until I tried removing that enclosing tag that I made progress. I added binding redirects for each assembly that I saw an exception raised for and it finally worked.

Below is my full app.config. The part that I needed to add in order to resolve this issue was everything within the `<runtime>` tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.ObjectModel" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.11.0" newVersion="4.0.11.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.11.0" newVersion="4.0.11.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection.Extensions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.11.0" newVersion="4.0.11.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.11.0" newVersion="4.0.11.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I pushed the change to [this repository](https://github.com/kaitlynbrown/SystemRuntimeFail) fixing the issue