# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

My code works fine locally and from Visual Studio 2017. but when i deploy it on my live server or any other machine i get the below error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Target Framework: 4.6
any suggestion?

Comment: use this link maybe it work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755274/visual-studio-2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4