# .NET Core 3.1 - Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

.NET Core 3.1 console app generates error during build -

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

But it works on .NET Core 3.0 version.

I'm using Microsoft.Orleans. This is csproj -

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Orleans.Core" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansCodeGenerator.Build" Version="3.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please, share your code and `csproj` file

Comment: Please, add it to the question

Comment: Exact same problem [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/5245), you need the updated code generator.  Assuming they have one, you might be stuck on 3.0 until they catch up.  Just wait for the response on the github issue you added.

Comment: Answers here may be useful to (if you are arriving from a 4.2.2. problem and not Core) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755274/visual-studio-2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReubenBond helped me with solution. I used `Microsoft.Orleans.CodeGenerator.MSBuild` package instead of `Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansCodeGenerator.Build`.

Answer (score 10):

In my case Nischal Nigam's solution didn't worked out, so what I did, I updated the package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` from version `1.0...` to `3.0.11` and after that it started working just fine.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you load your project properly (not just the folder which contains the project). In my case, instead of loading the .csproj file, I loaded just the folder which contains the whole project. What I did then, reloaded and clicked the .csproj file explicitly, then it came back to normal.

Comment: So many obscure errors that I have encountered because of this

Answer (score 8):

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio - Version 16.4.5

Go to the following location and open the `devenv.exe.config` file in a text editor:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_1832c881\devenv.exe.config`

Paste this binding in `<configuration> -> <runtime> -> <assemblyBinding>`

> ```
> <dependentAssembly>
>   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
>   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
> </dependentAssembly>
> ```

After this, save the file and restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load your project by double clicking on the "NameOfYourFile.csproj"
2. In the menu bar, click Project => properties of "NameOfYourFile. Choose "Application" and select a valid Framework Target (the newest in the list).
3. Rebuil, it should work.