# Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, class-library, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a azure function app which has a dependency on another class library to accomplish certain functionalities.

**Azure Function Details:**
TargetFramework: net5.0
AzureFunctionsVersion : v3

**ClassLibrary Details:**
TargetFramework: net5.0

I referenced the classlibrary project in the AzureFunction.

**Azure Function Code:**

**Startup.cs:**

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MessageReceiver
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IMailSender, MailSender>();
        }
    }
}
```

**MessageReceiver.cs**

```
namespace ProcessReportRequests
{
    public class MessageReceiverDataFunction
    {
        private const string QUEUE_NAME = "message-queue";
        private readonly IMailSender _mailSender;
        private readonly ILogger<MessageReceiverDataFunction> _log;
        public MessageReceiverDataFunction(IMailSender mailSender, ILogger<MessageReceiverDataFunction> log)
        {
            _mailSender = mailSender ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mailSender));
            _log = log ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(log));
        }

        [FunctionName("MessageReceiver")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger(QUEUE_NAME, Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] string queueMessage)
        {
            _mailSender.SendPlaintextMail("my.test@gmail.com", "mytest");
            _log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {queueMessage}");
        }
    }
}
```

ClassLibrary :ReportUtility

**IMailSender.cs:**

```
public interface IMailSender
{
    void SendPlaintextMail(string recipientEmail, string recipientName);
}
```

**MailSender.cs**

```
public class MailSender : IMailSender
{
    public MailSender()
    {
    }

    public async void SendPlaintextMail(string recipientEmail, string recipientName)
    {
        var sender = new SmtpSender(() => new SmtpClient("xxx.yyyy.zzzz")
        {UseDefaultCredentials = false, Port = 10, Credentials = new NetworkCredential(recipientEmail, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"), EnableSsl = true, });
        Email.DefaultSender = sender;
        var email = await Email.From(emailAddress: "my.test@sendermail.com").To(emailAddress: recipientEmail, name: recipientName).Subject(subject: "Testing Email Subject").Body(body: "This is a plain text message").SendAsync();
    }
}
```

On testing the application I am getting an error as mentioned below :

```
2022-05-11T19:53:58.654 [Error] Executed 'MessageReceiver' (Failed, Id=f13f0402-7c74-4f39-a9e1-a65fa8f61af9, Duration=3ms)Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Can anyone provide their guidance to fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this try updating the function app to version 4.

Updating the following project values to:

```cs
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

and use this command:

`az functionapp config appsettings set --settings FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION=~4 -n <APP_NAME> -g <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>`

Reference:
[Migrating from 3.x to 4.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process,azure-cli,v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#migrating-from-3x-to-4x) ,
[.NET Core 3.1 - Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610009/net-core-3-1-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4-2-2-0)

Comment: Thanks @SuryasriKamini-MT for your response. It helped me to fix the issue :)