# Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetPlatformAttribute' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Good afternoon. I did a git clone of one project and when I tried to run it I got the following error. I tried many different ways to solve it. And I reinstalled .Net and updated/deleted the corresponding versions, and also tried to write information in the [.config file](`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610009/net-core-3-1-could-not-load-file-or -assembly-system-runtime-version-4-2-2-0`) and many other links. Could you tell me how to solve this problem?  Below I send a library, which I’m trying to [build](https://github.com/Esri/military-symbology/tree/dev).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ogny.jpg)

```
1>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets(268,9): error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetPlatformAttribute' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'
```

I also realized that for some reason it opens and tries to find the required version of the .Net framework here (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework) (or rather the System.Runtime library (although the maximum version of packages there is 4.0.30319)) , but all the versions that I downloaded are located in a different path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework). Trying to update and reinstall the .Net versions in VS Installer did not help. Also, trying to directly determine the snares for the library data in .csproj also did not help

```
<ItemGroup>
     <Reference Include="CoordinateConversionLibrary">
       <HintPath>C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\CoordinateConversionLibrary.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Runtime">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Core">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Core.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Drawing">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Drawing.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Web.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Web.Windows.Forms.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Web.Xml.Linq.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.Forms.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Data">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Xml">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="PresentationCore">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\PresentationCore.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="PresentationFramework">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\PresentationFramework.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="WindowsBase">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\WindowsBase.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xaml.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
```

I Googled and checked EVERY answer and method that was given on GitHub or StackOverFlow and it did not help. Thank you in advance