# How do I run unittests in an Azure pipeline, when I use x64 and .NET5?

Tags: azure-devops, 64-bit, mstest, .net-5, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a small demo project, with unit tests.
using .net5, and 64 bit/any cpu.

I am having trouble with them running in my azure pipeline.

I have made a runsetting file, but cannot specify the 5.0 net framework

I've made a failing unit test, but it doenst get run.

when I 'debug' it I get this in my azure log..

2021-03-04T16:29:27.9652466Z /TestAdapterPath:"C:\DevOps\Agent 2_work\3\s"
2021-03-04T16:29:27.9652833Z /diag:"C:\DevOps\Agent 2_work_temp\c9f3dc90-7d06-11eb-9f3e-ab7c238ad233.txt"
2021-03-04T16:29:28.0475388Z **Settings file provided does not conform to required format. An error occurred while loading the settings.  Error: Invalid setting 'RunConfiguration'. Invalid value 'AnyCPU' specified for 'TargetPlatform'..**
2021-03-04T16:29:28.2479067Z ##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe'
2021-03-04T16:29:28.2484150Z ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe'
2021-03-04T16:29:28.2516774Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.

my .runsettings are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!-- File name extension must be .runsettings -->
<RunSettings>
<!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
<RunConfiguration>
  <!-- Path relative to directory that contains .runsettings file-->
  <ResultsDirectory>.\bin\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
<!-- x86 or x64 -->
    <!-- You can also change it from the Test menu; 
         choose "Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects" -->
    <TargetPlatform>AnyCPU</TargetPlatform>
    <!-- Framework35 | [Framework40] | Framework45 ... todo Framework50 er ikke suporteret-->
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework45</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <!-- true or false -->
    <!-- Value that specifies the exit code when no tests are discovered -->
    <TreatNoTestsAsError>false</TreatNoTestsAsError>
     </RunConfiguration> 
</RunSettings>
```

Does ms Azure not support .net50 for unit testing, with vs tests?

Thanks for you thoughts..
Kenneth

Answer (score 0):

> I have made a runsetting file, but cannot specify the 5.0 net
> framework

**TargetFrameworkVersion**:

> `FrameworkCore10` for .NET Core sources, `FrameworkUap10` for
> UWP-based sources, `Framework45` for .NET Framework **4.5 and
> higher**, `Framework40` for .NET Framework 4.0, and `Framework35` for
> .NET Framework 3.5.
>
> This setting specifies the version of the unit test framework used to
> discover and execute the tests. It can be different from the version
> of the .NET platform that you specify in the build properties of the
> unit test project.
>
> If you omit the `TargetFrameworkVersion` element from the .runsettings
> file, the platform automatically determines the framework version
> based on the built binaries.

For the error:

> An error occurred while loading the settings. Error: Invalid setting
> 'RunConfiguration'. Invalid value 'AnyCPU' specified for
> 'TargetPlatform'

**TargetPlatform** : x86, x64

According to [the elements that the `RunConfiguration` element can include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019#runconfiguration-element), the `TargetPlatform` node does not provide the value of `AnyCPU`.

Comment: Thanks, I ,had gotten back to the x64, but will try to leave the targetframework veroin out.

Comment: 2021-03-05T09:03:31.4105258Z [MSTest][Discovery][C:\...\DummyUnitTest.dll] Unable to load types from the test source 'C:\...\DummyUnitTest.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2021-03-05T09:03:31.4106111Z Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified....

Cannot find the test. due to problesm locating system.runtime..... hmm.. - sounds kind of like the core of the problem ..

Comment: Sorry for the late response, you can refer to the workarounds provided by this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755274/visual-studio-2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4/42755305)