# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0' resolved after deleting .vs folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am getting a "Could not load file or assembly" error every time I build my project, and I can resolve it each time by closing the solution and deleting the .vs folder. After that I don't see any errors.

Closing my project and deleting the .vs folder gets rid of the error until I build again.

Are there any settings in VS I can check that might be causing this?

I have searched through the entire project for anything referencing a version containing 4.2 and haven't been able to find it.

The .csproj file looks like it contains the correct reference to 4.3.0 and so does the packages.config.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks similar to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755274/visual-studio-2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4#49078929). The solution for them was to change the version in the .csproj. It is possible your problem is the same. As they said
“ Originally my app.config contained:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

But the packages.config contained:

```
<package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" requireReinstallation="true" />
```

I modified the app.config entry to match packages.config for the newVersion:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

After the change, the issue was resolved.”