# Download file from box using box api in c#

Tags: c#, box

I have written the following code to download the file

```
var config = new BoxConfig(BoxClientId, BoxSecret, new Uri("http://localhost")); var session = new OAuthSession(access_token, refresh_token, 3600, "bearer");
client = new BoxClient(config, session);
Uri uri = await client.FilesManager.GetDownloadUriAsync(FileId);
```

But i am unable to create a client object as it is raising an exception

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly
>   'System. Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, Public Key
>   Token=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified

I included all the possible references in Box.V2

Is there any other method by which I can download the file without the need for client object.

Comment: Please check if this link resolves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822406/you-must-add-a-ref-to-system-runtime

Comment: It looks like you do not have credentials to create a file at the root folder of your PC.  Use a subfolder like : "http://localhost/temp"