# error powershell c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have got a simple class libary project in visual studio:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace EdoX_auslesen_xml
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "DemoNames")]
    public class Get_DemoNames : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = false)]
        public string Prefix;

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            var names = new string[] { "Chris", "Charlie", "Anne" };
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Prefix))
            {
                this.WriteObject(names, true);
            }
            else
            {
                var prefixed_names = names.Select(n => this.Prefix + n);
                this.WriteObject(prefixed_names, true);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

When I open PowerShell an try to "Get-DemoNames" an error occurs:

[image]

in English:

Get-DemoNames: the file or assebly "System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0. Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or a dependency of it was not found. The system cannot find the given file.
In line:1 sign:1
+ Get- DemoNames...

Comment: The error message in the image is in German. Also paste text, not images.

Comment: Get-DemoNames: the file or assebly "System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0. Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or a dependency of it was not found. The system cannot find the given file.

Comment: What if one of the users that wanted to help doesn't understand the language that the error message is displaying in :/ please add English translation for the error to get more users to help :)

Comment: try copying System.Runtime.dll next to exe

Comment: I added it to the Assemblies but it hasn't help

Comment: Your code is failing to get a dependency assembly. Try to reduce them to the minimal possible, set all of them to copy to the result folder, and check if after that same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a reference to System.Runtime.

View [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822406/you-must-add-a-ref-to-system-runtime) StackOverflow question.