# Error when using RazorTemplates library: 'CS0012: The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced'

Tags: c#, razor

On some machines, executing a razor template via **`RazorTemplates`** works OK.

On others, I receive the following message:

**`TemplateCompilationException`**

```
error CS0012: The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Info:

- This is within a WPF application running on .NET 4.7.
- The assembly has a reference to System.Runtime.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll (v4.1.1.0)
- However at runtime, this assembly does not show up in the 'Modules' list.

It seems the Attribute object exists in both System.Runtime and mscorlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is an underlying issue somewhere between win10 and the RazorTemplates library.

In the end i switched from RazorTemplates to RazorEngine: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

And there is a page here that explains how to fix the problem via a Resolver:

https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/416

Comment: nice find @Jon-Barker

Answer (score 0):

System.Runtime is part of the .Net Framework and is installed in the GAC during framework installation.

This could happen for two possible reasons:

1. It's not on the machine.
2. It's the wrong version.

For the machines this fails on check what version of the .Net runtime they have and/or inspect the GAC for this file and version.

Missing the framework, install it. :-)

If machines have a version but it's not the expected version do either:

1. Install the correct framework version
2. Use a [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) in your config file

Comment: Unfortunately it's not quite this simple otherwise I would have solved it :)

- The machines have .net framework 4.7.2 installed and the file exists in the GAC on both the machines that work, and the ones that don't

- System.Runtime is references as a nuget package in our solution, but this file isn't loaded in the modules. As mentioned though, the Attribute class exists in mscorlib, so missing this file shouldn't affect anything

Comment: Well I have found: adding to the config the assembly -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822406/build-error-you-must-add-a-reference-to-system-runtime.  This would be your app.config but it's not a compile issue....  so feels like a stretch.  After that, is -> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2971005/error-message-when-you-compile-applications-to-target-the-net-framewor Again, a stretch as this is about VS and developer pack (and 4.5.X not 4.7) but I did find that my 4.7 folder has facades with System.Runtime in it, again VS box vs deployed machine... so both feel like a stretch.

Comment: To confirm my assumption - This is a runtime issue on deployed machines vs. a compile time issue on dev boxes?  If it's runtime on deployed machines, these machines don't have VS on them?

Comment: All machines don't have VS installed. The issue occurrs on some and doesn't occurr on others unfortunately. I haven't been able to work out exactly what the determining factor is yet. I'll give the config change a go and see what happens. Thanks for taking the time to investigate.

Comment: All machines don't have VS installed.  Are you saying some do?  If yes, are they the one's working...?

Comment: None of the machines have VS installed. Some of them it works OK. Some of them it doesn't work

Comment: OK... just wanted to make sure my assumptions of these boxes being just deployed locations not dev machines.  I still think my commented links are stretches but worth investigating.

Comment: And the machines that don't work, you did confirm that the GAC'd versions is the version expected?  Without a binding redirect, if it's not the exact version expected the GAC won't load them....