# What does the web.config compilation/assemblies element do?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I had a problem where, working on a new MVC project, as soon as I added `Html.Partial("Name")` to my `_Layout.cshtml` page, ASP.NET would throw this exception on page load:

> error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is not in a referenced assembly is defined. Add a reference to the Assembly "System.Runtime, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a" added.

The fix is to add this to the `web.config`, compilation element:

```
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </assemblies>
```

I'd love to know why this fixes the issue.

What's odd is that the new MVC app I'm using has a load of *WebForms ASPX* pages that work a treat. I've copied a ton of legacy *WebForms* stuff into this new MVC project, acres of code, and everything works, and without the `Html.Partial` call, even my MVC view renders.

So what on Earth is going on? What does this config do and why aren't the normal project references and target framework settings enough?

Comment: The docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.compilationsection.assemblies don't say much

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This is caused by a disconnect and limitation between the build time and the runtime environments of an *ASP.NET/MVC* project. Most code in a Web project is compiled at build time (ie F5) with exception to views (both *Razor* and inline *ASPX* code) which are built dynamically at runtime (ie within IIS).

For the most part, we attempt to make these two environments *exactly* the same and you will not typically notice any difference. Unfortunately. you've run into one of those cases where there **is** a difference and you've needed to manually add a reference to make the runtime mimic build-time.

What's happening, is that you likely have a dependency on a portable library (at a guess, `Microsoft.Net.Http`). *Portable Libraries* are a little different to normal libraries, and we need extra references to make the compiler happy. At build-time we detect a dependency on a portable library and automatically add all the references to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades`. Unfortunately, the runtime doesn't do this and you need to manually add these references until we fix this in a future release.

For future reference, you can just grab the following section and paste this directly into Web.Config (this represents the snapshot for 4.5):

```
 <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Diagnostics.Contracts, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Dynamic.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Globalization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.IO, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Linq.Parallel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Linq.Queryable, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Net.NetworkInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Net.Requests, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.ObjectModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Reflection.Emit, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Reflection.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Reflection.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Resources.ResourceManager, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.InteropServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Security.Principal, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Duplex, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Text.Encoding, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Threading, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.XDocument, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.XmlSerializer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave and apologies for taking ages to tick your answer.

Comment: I'm having the exactly same problem, but this time, its not an MVC application. Instead, it is an Azure Worker role that hosts a Workflow application and the same error happens when I'm loading the workflow from a byte[] definition. I've posted a question here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198348/failure-compiling-workflow-definition any clues? There is no compilation tag in APP.config :(

Comment: When you say it will be fixed on next release, so all these references will be removed by the update? Or should we remove them manually?

Comment: I had to add this to the compilation tag that already existed in Views/Web.config

Comment: Where can we find snapshots for versions different to 4.5 e.g. 4.5.1?
Where can we find information about what fixes is MS planning regarding that issue and when to expect them?

Comment: The references in the web.config are still required at 2018, when you are calling code from a PCL in a runtime compiled (ASPX, ASCX, ...) file. (tested with WebForms ASP.Net 4.7. VS 2017 15.8.3 and Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform v 2.0.0 installed )

Comment: For 4.8, C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\Facades exists.  Does this represent the list of dlls for the 4.8 version of the framework?  Should we be listing all 104 items under compilation assemblies?  I had to add netstandard.dll  to get some things working and that's listed in this directory.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the exact same error after switching to VS 2017 & C# 7.1 and adding references to System.ValueTuple into my .NET 4.6 ASP.NET project

Problem solved by [activating Roslyn in ASP.NET projects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/12/07/new-feature-to-enable-c-6-vb-14/) without fiddling with references in web.config

Added benefit of this is you can use new C# features in aspx pages and MVC views

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when I cleared assemblies due to being in an IIS application where the parent was referencing things I didn't want.

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <clear />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
```

Should have been obvious in hindsight, but the error didn't really seem linked to the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation.I had an MVC project with Unity. Project was targeting .Net version 4.5.1 but my build machine was missing the 4.5.1 folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework folder.

So what solved my problem was copying v4.5.1 folder from my dev machine to the build machine.

You can find the link to the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877047/1295518)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 MVC.RAZOR fixed by adding this to web app web.config section:  here is a snippet of my Web.Config just after system.web node:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```