# Compilation error at runtime from Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage version 4.0.30506

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting the following error when I try to use version 4.0.30506 (unfortunately we are tied to this version of ASP.NEt Web API for now) of the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage nuget package. I am using Windows 7 and .NET 4.5.

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Source Error:


Line 11: 
Line 12:     // Group APIs by controller
Line 13:     ILookup<string, ApiDescription> apiGroups = Model.ToLookup(api => api.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName);
Line 14: }
Line 15:
```

[image]

As far as I can see I have all the correct references for this to work. I have tried looking for a System.Runtime assembly as it suggests, but I can't find it on my system. I have added using statements to the top of Index.cshtml, but with no affect.

```
@using System
@using System.Runtime
```

Any suggestions of what is causing this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the web.config compilation/assemblies element do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675171/what-does-the-web-config-compilation-assemblies-element-do)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

check your web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: The first snippet gave me a parser error when added to my Index.cshtml. Is this valid Razor syntax? It works with the second snippet but without the first.

Comment: @jamesj a typo # instead of % but i'm not a razor guru... i was not sure about it...

Comment: @jamesj happy to help! :D than I remove the first snippet

Comment: I was using an extension method on enum in my view and this helped me to fix up my view compile issues - thanks! :)

Comment: yes, it works, but I wonder why the config file is not automatically updated, it was just  <compilation debug="true" />

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this error disappeared when I **removed System.Collections.Immutable.dll from Bin** directory. This DLL is from NuGet package and is available only for Win8 platforms and I was working with Win7. So it might help you too..

Comment: I have added then removed the `System.Collections.Immutable.dll` and start getting the error. After deleting it from bin, the error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error after updating all Nuget packages in an MVC 5, .NET 4.5.1 project, and thanks to [Dmitry Lyalin's post](http://www.lyalin.com/2014/04/25/the-type-system-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-reference-mvc-pcl-issue/) discovered the issue related to an updated Nuget package that has become a Portable Class Library.

For those who like to dig, I figured out the culprit by doing the following:

1. Unload the project [image: unloading a VS project]
2. Edit the project
    [image: editing a project]
3. Search for "portable" [image: found an unexpected portable library]
4. Having found Humanizer, I changed it back to pre-PCL version 1.37.7, retested the page, and found that everything worked again.

Knowing the culprit(s), Humanizer in my case, there's two options:

1. Cap the Humanizer Nuget at version 1.x.y so as not to use the new PCL libraries in v2 via *allowedVersions* attribute in packages.config:
   `<package id="Humanizer " version="1.37.7" allowedVersions="[1,2)" />`
2. Do what giammin suggests in his answer and add the System.Runtime assembly under system.web in web.config:
   `<system.web><compilation ...><assemblies><add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /></assemblies></compilation></system.web>`

Comment: Thank you for discovering this.