# Visual Studio Online MsBuild Fail on System.Object

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, azure-devops

The Build Server is producing this error :

```
The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

The Web.Config contains that configuration:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
```

I have also changed the MsBuild Argument to

```
 /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5.2
```

This has not helped. Still the same error.
I also see multiple warning warning on the Build Server:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (990): 
The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" were not found. 
To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or 
retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK 
or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global 
Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore
your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

How can I make the Build Server (Visual Studio Online) build this .Net 4.5.2 project ?

### Edit

I also have a lot of warning message of this type:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (990): 
The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" were not found. 
To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget 
your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting 
Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC)
 and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be 
correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

Comment: Are you sure .NET 4.5 is installed on this server?

Comment: This might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675171/what-does-the-web-config-compilation-assemblies-element-do/19942274#19942274

Comment: @Mick Yes I am pretty sure (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Fdotnet%2Farchive%2F2014%2F08%2F07%2Fmoving-to-the-net-framework-4-5-2.aspx&ei=sV_zU7irA6O_igLqwYHYAg&usg=AFQjCNG-sikhf-AQcZBtoQiWlqGeJYzIfg&sig2=NUpmJ7eJHkVokT4gw3AU5Q&bvm=bv.73231344,d.cGE) and I will check you link back home tonight

Comment: Does not work.I will try to compile in 4.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Online (VSO) does not support the latest .Net Framework. I got an intern discussion with the VSO team and this is planned in a near future. The short term solution is to compile with a previous .Net framework until VSO release this new feature.

Comment: Having the same issue here and couldn't find much information about this. Do you have any update?

Comment: This is working for me since about 2 months. I guess they have updated something on the backend.