# Asp.net MVC EditorFor "The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Employees", FormMethod.Post, new { encType = "multipart/form-data", name = "EmployeeForm" }))
{
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Surname
        </th>
        <th>
            ID Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Birthdate
        </th>
        <th>
            Action
        </th>
    </tr>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employees)
</table>
}
```

This line Line 32:         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employees) gives the following Error

```
CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

I have used this similiar approach in another project which did not give this error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Look for this in your web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

Add the `System.Runtime` assembly as follows:

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>     
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />   
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

This is usually caused due to MVC and PCL as detailed in the following article:

[**The type ‘System.Object’ is defined in an assembly that is not reference (MVC + PCL issue)**](http://www.lyalin.com/2014/04/25/the-type-system-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-reference-mvc-pcl-issue/)

Comment: Worked, thank you. I had a PCL Library which I had my classes. will also read the full article you linked

Comment: Thank you for your short and clear answer. It worked as I had referenced PCL into my MVC project.

Comment: the link is dead, other than that you saved my day

Comment: @Toolkit :) The above web site has a 'Error establishing a database connection'. They need to ask some questions on here to get it fixed.

Comment: Broken link in this answer mirrors the info on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675171/what-does-the-web-config-compilation-assemblies-element-do/19942274#19942274)