# Add a reference to the assembly with Unity v.2017

Tags: c#, .net, macos, unity-game-engine

I have an issue with the new version of Unity3D, when i compile, i have exactly the same issue of this post : [What does the web.config compilation/assemblies element do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675171/what-does-the-web-config-compilation-assemblies-element-do/45147635#45147635)
But i can't find the web.config file on osx and i don't know if Unity is linked to it.
If someone can explain me, or just send me the path of this file.