# Roslyn compilation doesn't resolve mscorlib references

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm working on a project where I compile projects from a solution using Roslyn.

```
foreach (var projectId in solution.GetProjectDependencyGraph().GetTopologicallySortedProjects())
{
    var project = solution.GetProject(projectId);
    var compilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
    var errors = compilation.GetDiagnostics().Where(d => d.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);
    // ...
```

Compilation contains errors such as

> error CS0012: The type 'Task' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Why Roslyn won't accept an existing reference to mscorlib?

- [msdn for System.Threading.Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) points out that this type is indeed located in mscorlib.dll
- PublicKeyToken b03f5f7f11d50a3a matches mscorlib's

Are there some `CompilationOptions` that I should consider?
Per [this thread](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/256) I tried `assemblyIdentityComparer: DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default` but it didn't help. I tried to work with `metadataReferenceResolver` but couldn't find much information about it.

Following the solution in [Roslyn has no reference to System.Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907305/roslyn-has-no-reference-to-system-runtime) I implemented code that ensures that a project has references to mscorlib.dll, System.Core.dll, System.dll and System.Runtime.dll, such that my **project** and **compilation** have the references:

Side note: Reference #7 has been added this way. The project already had references #1, 2 and 3, and removing them and replacing with ones from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework didn't solve the issue.

```
project.MetadataReferences.ToList()
Count = 8
    [0]: Assembly Path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll'
    [1]: Assembly Path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll'
    [2]: Assembly Path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll'
    [3]: Assembly Path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll'
    [4]: Assembly Path='C:\Users\Amadeus\Documents\GitHub\InterProcessQueue\src\MemoryMappedQueue\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.0.0-rc1-build1030\build\_common\xunit.abstractions.dll'
    [5]: Assembly Path='C:\Users\Amadeus\Documents\GitHub\InterProcessQueue\src\MemoryMappedQueue\packages\xunit.assert.2.0.0-rc1-build2826\lib\portable-net45+aspnetcore50+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS\xunit.assert.dll'
    [6]: Assembly Path='C:\Users\Amadeus\Documents\GitHub\InterProcessQueue\src\MemoryMappedQueue\packages\xunit.extensibility.core.2.0.0-rc1-build2826\lib\portable-net45+aspnetcore50+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS\xunit.core.dll'
    [7]: Assembly Path='C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.dll'

compilation.ExternalReferences.ToList()
Count = 9
    [0]: Assembly Path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll'
    [1]: Assembly Path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll'
    [2]: Assembly Path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll'
    [3]: Assembly Path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll'
    [4]: Assembly Path='C:\Users\Amadeus\Documents\GitHub\InterProcessQueue\src\MemoryMappedQueue\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.0.0-rc1-build1030\build\_common\xunit.abstractions.dll'
    [5]: Assembly Path='C:\Users\Amadeus\Documents\GitHub\InterProcessQueue\src\MemoryMappedQueue\packages\xunit.assert.2.0.0-rc1-build2826\lib\portable-net45+aspnetcore50+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS\xunit.assert.dll'
    [6]: Assembly Path='C:\Users\Amadeus\Documents\GitHub\InterProcessQueue\src\MemoryMappedQueue\packages\xunit.extensibility.core.2.0.0-rc1-build2826\lib\portable-net45+aspnetcore50+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS\xunit.core.dll'
    [7]: Assembly Path='C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.dll'
    [8]: Compilation (C#): MemoryMappedQueue
```

- How can I get Roslyn to compile this project?
- Are there any `CompilationOptions` I should use?
- Is [Roslyn's issue #970](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/970) related to this?

Comment: [Resembles this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2971005) too.  It is still beta quality, limp along by adding the reference.  It is located in the *Facades* subdirectory.

Comment: Yes it resembles this but this solution didn't fix the issue. I'll try to post a minimal solution where this issue happens.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Kevin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678625/kevin-pilch-bisson) [answer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1894), this can be resolved by specifying a property for `MSBuildWorkspace`:

```
var props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
props["CheckForSystemRuntimeDependency"] = "true";
var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(props);
```

Now solutions opened in `msWorkspace` will correctly resolve their references.

Comment: That did not work for me, I'm using VS 2015 RC. Anyone? Any update?

Answer (score 0):

Is the project that is producing the errors a non-portable project that is referencing a portable project? If so, observe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416135/how-can-i-resolve-all-references-with-roslyns-opensolutionasync) -- you'll have to add facade references.

Comment: No, both projects in the solution are Class Libraries targeting .NET 4.5