# SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(typeSyntax) returns null

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am having problems resolving *some* types in Roslyn.
Most of the times it works as expected
But in some occasions, in some files, some types fail to resolve.
This is the code that I use to handle types:

```
private string GetTypeName(TypeSyntax type)
{
    var si = _model.GetSymbolInfo(type);
    var s = si.Symbol;
    if (s == null)
    {
        var ti = _model.GetTypeInfo(type);
        if (ti.Type?.Kind == SymbolKind.ErrorType)
        {
            return "**error type**";
        }

        return "**unknown type**";
    }
    return GetTypeNameFromSymbol(s as ITypeSymbol);
}
```

I pass a TypeSyntax from various different expressions and declarations.
It seems to be per document and per type failure.
In some documents it cannot resolve `Task` as a type, and in some it cannot resolve different exception types.

I am unable to create a small example that reproduces this.
I use the above code in my C# to Kotlin transpiler:
https://github.com/rogeralsing/ProjectExodus

In some cases I end up in the "**error type**" branch.
And in some in the "**unknown type**"

And the failure occurs only when trying to transpile some fairly large solutions from what I can see so far.

What can cause this?
I get my semantic model from the document like so:

```
var model = await d.GetSemanticModelAsync();
var root = await d.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
```

Is there something else I should do?

EDIT:
I've managed to extract this information:
It says the containing assembly is missing.
Why is that? the source solution opens and builds fine in VS.NET

[image]

Comment: What about `_model.GetDeclaredSymbol(type)`? Does it return some value for you?

Comment: Yes, when `s` is null, GetDeclaredSymbol also gives null

Comment: What syntax node does it fail for?

Comment: Does [CanGetSemanticInfo](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compilation/CSharpSemanticModel.cs,58) return false for your syntax node?

Comment: That is on the CSharpSemanticModel which is internal and cannot be used, the model you get from GetSemanticModelAsync is a "SyntaxTreeSemanticModel"

Comment: Are you use `MSBuildWorkspace`? If so, can you chek `Diagnostics`?

Comment: I got two errors, one for each project in the solution: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rogeralsing/5e74161049a813e5e4a78074e62d6562/raw/7d0debe4fca5d1ccca4c68cc2df1b4899ead144a/errorroslyn.txt

Comment: I removed the faulty entries in the csproj and the diagnostic errors disappeared, the type resolution issue still exists

Comment: This is a problem with references passed to the compilation. From a Compilation, call GetDiagnostics() and you'll see errors such as "The type System.Object is not defined or imported". Most likely during the build process something goes awry and the reference doesn't make it. Can you point us to the place where you're loading the analyzed project? Does it build fine from the command line?

Comment: Also see if any of this might help: https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/SourceBrowser/blob/master/src/HtmlGenerator/Pass1-Generation/SolutionGenerator.cs#L125-L131

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416135/how-can-i-resolve-all-references-with-roslyns-opensolutionasync

Comment: You probably need to add the appropriate metadata references to your Compilation. I say this because I was just fighting the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have the same class-file saved as e.g "class1.old" and you are loading it in your prj/solution workspace. In that case it will create ambiguity!