# Issue with IReadOnlyList on WP8.1 .NET 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1

First a little background:
I'm trying to write an app for Windows Phone (for home use, nothing commercial) to send data over bluetooth to an Arduino.
I'm using Visual Studio Comunity 2015, a Windwos Phone with 8.1 (Denim) and my PC is also Windows 8.1.

I had a hard time finding anything useful to use bluetooth on Windowws Phone for this kind of application and finally found this library :
[BluetoothManager.cs](https://github.com/OmarElabd/Titan-V/blob/master/Titan%20VI/Titan%20VI.Controller/Titan%20VI.Controller.WindowsPhone/BluetoothManager.cs)

With the rest of the Github project I'm trying to understand and use it, but each time I get an error :

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll

After using several breakpoints, I found the cause, which is [Line 74 of the library](https://github.com/OmarElabd/Titan-V/blob/master/Titan%20VI/Titan%20VI.Controller/Titan%20VI.Controller.WindowsPhone/BluetoothManager.cs#L74).
When adding a watch for the variable pairedDevice, I get

> error CS0012: The type 'IReadOnlyList<>' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I tried several things the main answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349189/the-type-system-idisposable-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced), but nothing worked.

- Installing the fix from Microsoft changed nothing
- I don't have an App.config or Web.config file (because it's WP8.1 ?)
- Adding .dlls from the Facade-folder says that it's already referenced

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: What type of windows phone 8.1 project are you using?  I think this library needs to be used with a windows phone 8.1 RT not silverlight project

Comment: It's definitely not a Silverlight. I chose "Blank App (Windows Phone)"